# How can i get the entity value after checking the type?

Tags: json, node.js, parsing

```
    (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {entity: "lovely meeting", type: "Calendar.Subject", startIndex: 53, endIndex: 66, score: 0.9183444}
1: {entity: "california", type: "Calendar.Location", startIndex: 27, endIndex: 36, score: 0.922538459}
2: {entity: "today", type: "builtin.datetimeV2.date", startIndex: 18, endIndex: 22, resolution: {…}}
3: {entity: "4am", type: "builtin.datetimeV2.time", startIndex: 41, endIndex: 43, resolution: {…}}length: 4__proto__: Array(0)
```

These 4 elements are part of `Entities`, what i want is to check if type is equal to let's say `Calender.Location` and worth noting that we don't always have the 4 elements we could have one or none, and even when we do have 4 the entity type `Calender.Location` doesn't have to be index number `1`, what i have tried included `testvar.entities.length` and `testvar.entities[0].type` not knowing the `ID` of each makes it impossible .

Example of what i want:

i want to parse the `Json` input for a type `Calendar.location` in entities, it might exist and might not and its exact id is not known(ranges between 0 and 4), if i do find it i should return the entity associated with it in this case `california`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const test =[
  {entity: "lovely meeting", type: "Calendar.Subject", startIndex: 53, endIndex: 66, score: 0.9183444},
  {entity: "california", type: "Calendar.Location", startIndex: 27, endIndex: 36, score: 0.922538459},
  {entity: "today", type: "builtin.datetimeV2.date", startIndex: 18, endIndex: 22, resolution: {}},
  {entity: "4am", type: "builtin.datetimeV2.time", startIndex: 41, endIndex: 43, resolution: {}}
]


const getentitiesByType  = (arr,type) => {
  
 for(let i in arr ){
    if(arr[i].type === type){
       return arr[i].entity;
    }
  }

};

console.log(getentitiesByType(test,"Calendar.Location"))
```